# Update BLOB column in table when > 4k

Tags: oracle, blob

The situation is that a row is inserted into a table, and one of the columns is a BLOB.  The BLOB is read from a file and works fine when inserting a new row.  Here is the code used to perform the INSERT:

```
DECLARE
  l_dir    VARCHAR2(20) := 'TEMP_DIRECTORY';
  l_file   VARCHAR2(20) := 'AAPL.pdf';
  l_bfile  BFILE;
  l_blob   BLOB;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO article_history (ticker, date_published, pdf_report)
  VALUES ('AAPL', SYSDATE, EMPTY_BLOB())
  RETURN pdf_report INTO l_blob;

  l_bfile := BFILENAME(l_dir, l_file);
  DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
  DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_blob, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile));
  DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile);

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

But the BLOB column is not populated at insert time, it will be updated later.  So, my question is:  How to retrieve the LOB Locator and update the BLOB column with the contents from the file?

Not sure how to write the code to do that.

Comment: select the blob column into l_blob with a standard `select pdf_report into l_blob where....` and do the bfilename/dbms_lob work that you're doing above.

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly the same as you are doing with the `INSERT` but use `SELECT` to get the BLOB handle rather than `INSERT ... RETURNING ... INTO ...`

```sql
DECLARE
  l_dir    VARCHAR2(20) := 'TEMP_DIRECTORY';
  l_file   VARCHAR2(20) := 'AAPL.pdf';
  l_bfile  BFILE;
  l_blob   BLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT pdf_report
  INTO   l_blob
  FROM   article_history
  WHERE  ticker = 'AAPL';

  l_bfile := BFILENAME(l_dir, l_file);
  DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
  DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_blob, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile));
  DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile);

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a function that  reads the file and returns a BLOB. That way you can use it whenever you need to insert/update your tables' BLOB columns.

```sql
FUNCTION FILE2BLOB  (mDir       IN  VARCHAR2,
                     mFileName  IN  VARCHAR2) RETURN BLOB
IS
BEGIN
    Declare 
        mBLOB       BLOB := Empty_Blob();
        mBinFile    BFILE := BFILENAME(mDir, mFileName);
    Begin
        DBMS_LOB.OPEN(mBinFile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);             -- Open BFILE
        DBMS_LOB.CreateTemporary(mBLOB, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.Session);    -- BLOB locator initialization
        DBMS_LOB.OPEN(mBLOB, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);               -- Open BLOB locator for writing
        DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile(mBLOB, mBinFile, DBMS_LOB.getLength(mBinFile));   -- Reading BFILE into BLOB
        DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(mBLOB);              -- Close BLOB locator
        DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(mBinFile);           -- Close BFILE
        RETURN mBLOB;       -- Return BLOB
    End;
END FILE2BLOB;
```

To insert BLOB into table column ...

```sql
Insert Into article_history (ticker, date_published, pdf_report) 
VALUES ( 'AAPL', SYSDATE, FILE2BLOB('your_directory_obj', 'your_file_name') );
```

To update table's BLOB column ...

```sql
Update your_table_name 
    Set your_blob_column = FILE2BLOB('your_directory_obj', 'your_file_name') 
Where your_pk_column = PK_VALUE;
```